# What can I do to prevent the data of my d3 chart from sticking out?

Tags: json, d3.js

[image]

I am a novice developer in Korea.

The long data of my d3 chart is projecting like an image.

How can I do to prevent the bulging of this json data?

Comment: can u show some code example of how u added the data to the d3 json library
and reference to d3 library property related to data labels that u might hv tried but didnt work out?

Comment: add this style for the chart div https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/ - this class to each of your data plot : `.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: I doubt `ellipsis` will work with SVG text